# How to refer to items in Dictionary<string, string> by integer index?

Tags: c#, dictionary, indexing

I made a **Dictionary`<string, string>`** collection so that I can quickly reference the items by their **string identifier**.

But I now also need to **access** this collective by **index counter** (foreach won't work in my real example).

**What do I have to do to the collection below so that I can access its items via integer index as well?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestDict92929
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> events = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            events.Add("first", "this is the first one");
            events.Add("second", "this is the second one");
            events.Add("third", "this is the third one");

            string description = events["second"];
            Console.WriteLine(description);

            string description = events[1]; //error
            Console.WriteLine(description);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't.  And your question infers your belief that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is an ordered list.  It is not.  If you need an ordered dictionary, this type isn't for you.

Perhaps [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) is your friend.  It provides integer indexing.

Answer (score 5):

You can not. As was said - a dictionary has no order.

Make your OWN CONTAINER that exposes `IList` and `IDictionary`... and internally manages both (list and dictionary). This is what I do in those cases. So, I can use both methods.

Basically

```
class MyOwnContainer : IList, IDictionary
```

and then internally

```
IList _list = xxx
IDictionary _dictionary = xxx
```

then in add / remove / change... update both.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>` class in the `System.Collections.ObjectModel` namespace for this. There's only one gotcha: it is abstract. So you will have to inherit from it and create your own :-). Otherwise use the non-generic `OrderedDictionary` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't: an index is meaningless because a dictionary is not ordered - and the order in which items are returned when enumerating can change as you add and remove items.  You need to copy the items to a list to do that.

Answer (score 2):

`Dictionary` is not sorted/ordered, so index numbers would be meaningless.

Comment: You're thinking of it backwards.  Think of it as primarily a `List` but with methods like Insert, Remove, IndexOf - but instead of just adding items and retrieving via an integer indexer, you can get to them via some other way too - typically a string.  The `DataRow` class in a DataTable functions somewhat like this.